# Gulp-eslint causing configuration errors

Tags: javascript, gulp, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

When trying to run my linter standalone from the command line `eslint .`, everything works as expected. The issue comes when I try to run an "eslint" task via gulp.

My `.eslintrc` extends `airbnb-base` which is where the error is being thrown:

```
Configuration for rule "prefer-destructuring" is invalid:
    Value "data["0"].VariableDeclarator" has additional properties.
    Value "data["0"].AssignmentExpression" has additional properties.
```

This is 1 of a couple of errors all of the same structure. The configuration rule is valid having looked at the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring#rule-details):

```
// Prefer destructuring from arrays and objects
// http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring
'prefer-destructuring': ['error', {
  VariableDeclarator: {
    array: false,
    object: true,
  },
  AssignmentExpression: {
    array: true,
    object: true,
  },
}, {
  enforceForRenamedProperties: false,
}],
```

Looking at the , the rule configuration seems to be accurate.

- eslint @ 4.16.0
- eslint-config-airbnb-base @ 12.1.0
- gulp-eslint @ 3.0.1
- gulp @ 3.9.1

I am very unsure as to what this error is so any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was simply that my `gulp-eslint` package was out-of-date. I was running @ 3.0.1 whereas the latest stable release at this time was 4.0.2